# How to implement message chunking in a wcf ria service for silverlight 4.0?

Tags: wcf-ria-services

I am very much new to this message chunking things.Just have a brief idea that when ever your volume of data being transferred from your service to client increases chunking helps you  to get your data in chunks so as to avoid the time out error.
Correct me if I am wrong

But I am not able to find any links or any working samples on how to implement it in wcf ria service with silverlight client.

Can any one please throw some idea or share any sample code snippet or any link to start with.
I am in a great need of this as I have to implement it in one of my project.

Thanks in advance,
Subrat

Answer (score 0):

One approach that I had used in my previous project. (not a WCF RIA service project)

**Client**

1. Break the stream into chunks that can be transferred over HTTP (around 4k chars).
2. Make sure that asynchronous method is used to handle exception and success.
3. Since the size is not large, you can use string as a parameter or byte array.
4. The other way is to use WebClient with ByteStream as well. But it will be hard to implement.

**Server**

1. The WCF RIA Service can expose a method with string as parameter.
2. Data that is flowing in can be stored in a session object.

Comment: Thanks for your response.But I would appreciate if you provide me some link or some sample code snippet on how to implement it in Silverlight wcf ria service context.Again my concern whether Chunk would be apply when your data is of type Stream>if i hav eto return a list of data then how could I achive this through chunking?